# Attach additional node to postgres primary server as warm standby

Tags: postgresql

I have set up Postgres 11 streaming replication cluster. Standby is a "hot standby". Is it possible to attach the second standby as a warm standby?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are talking about [WAL file shipping](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/warm-standby.html) when you are speaking of a “warm standby”.

Sure, there is nothing that keeps you from adding a second standby that ships WAL files rather than directly attaching to the primary, but I don't see the reason for that.

Answer (score -1):

According to [this decent documentation of Postgres 11 streaming replication](http://www.interdb.jp/pg/pgsql11.html) architecture, you *can* set the **`sync_state`** of a 2nd slave instance to be **`potential`**. This means that if/when the 1st **`sync`** slave fails, the detected failure (through ACK communication) will result in the 2nd slave will move from `potential` to `sync` becoming the **active** replication server. --see **Section 11.3 - Managing Multiple Stand-by Servers** in that link for more details.

Comment: Note that I have not tried to accomplish simultaneous active sync and potential replication servers.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question, and it is utterly wrong. You cannot *set* `sync_state`, it is a column in the `pg_stat_replication` view that *shows* the state the standby is in.